# Where can I get dsquery and other tools useful for debugging Active Directory issues?

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

The `dsquery` command line tool is mentioned in the solution to several questions about Active Directory. However, my workstation does not have this command line tool. Where do I get it?

Comment: To get the dsquery command on latest Windows10 go to: Apps and Features - Manage optional features - Add a Feature - install RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dsquery` tool, and other command line tools for Active Directory are available in the [Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C16AE515-C8F4-47EF-A1E4-A8DCBACFF8E3).

Answer (score 22):

For Windows 7, it's part of the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) feature pack:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

This can be used for W2003 and W2008 servers.
Information on how to install these with the *dism* command can be found in [my blog post](https://www.actualadmins.com/windows-7w2008-managing-features-with-the-command-line-and-installing-the-remote-server-administration-tools-rsat/).

For Windows 8, it's on:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972

This one is for managing W2012 servers:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Comment: After installing, remember to go into your "Windows Features" control panel and turn it on through "Remote Server Administration Tools | Role Administration Tools | AD DS and AD LDS Tools"

Comment: For windows 10 it is available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: All tools will be enabled by default in Windows 10 right after the installation.

Comment: The blog post http://www.actualadmins.com/entry/windows-7-w2008-managing-features-with-the-command-line-and-the-remote-server-administration-tools/ is gone.

Comment: The blog post link has been repaired.

Answer (score 8):

Even better than dsquery is the adfind and admod tools from [joeware](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/)

Much more powerful.

Comment: Great tool, easy to use, with `AdFind.exe -h hostname -f userPrincipalName="LOGIN*"` you can easily find your entry and understand the structure of the directory.

Answer (score 3):

On Win2008 and Win2012:

To install Active Directory Domain Services Tools on a server that runs Windows Server 2008 & 2012

Control Panel | Programs and Features | Add/remove Windows Features

Go through wizard to "Add Roles and Features Wizard"

Dig into Features

Click down to: Remote Server Administration Tools, | Role Administration Tools, | Active Directory Domain Services Tools, and then click Next.

Click Install.

Answer (score -1):

I am dealing with Windows 7 x86. After installing (Windows6.1-KB958830-x86-RefreshPkg.msu). I do ENABLE these FEATURES.
[image: RSAT under Programs and Features]